# What's correct way to use default constructor for XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Could you help me to find an error please?
I'm trying to use XmlSerialize:

```
public static void ProcessLines(List<string> allLines, out pfm pfm)
    {
        ...
        pfm = newPfm;
        pfm forseril = new pfm("");
        XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(pfm));
        StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("myFileName.xml");
        mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, forseril);
        myWriter.Close();

    }
```

And here is that thing that I think should be a default constructor:

```
 [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Pfm", Namespace = null)]
    public class pfm
    {

        public pfm(string data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public string data;

        public Ctl ctl
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
```

I used an istruction from Microsoft site: [instruction](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/330592)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `XmlSerializer` requires is a *parameterless constructor* -- a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) with no arguments.  Thus your `pfm` needs a constructor as follows:

```
public class pfm
{
    pfm() : this("") { }

    public pfm(string data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

It doesn't need to be public.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B4sX1n).